# Replacing values from JSON result with HTML and CSS

Tags: json, reactjs, fetch

I'll try to explain this the best I can. There is a JSON result which separates every paragraph of the text and marks them with 0 or 1 (or even 0.3 etc). The Stringified results on the frontend shows those numbers too. Is there a way to replace these and apply CSS styles based on the value (0, 0.1, or 1)?

the JSON:

[image: code]

RAW:

```
"content": [
          [
            0.0, 
            "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.", 
            []
          ], 
          [
            0.0, 
            "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.", 
            []
          ], 
          [
            1, 
            "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.", 
            []
          ]
        ], 
...
```

What I get in the front end is:

`0Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.0Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.1Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.`

I should get:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
```

With 0s and 1s replacedby html (and classes)

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to map over that content and pull the values out of each item, then render them.

```
data.content.map((item, i) =>
  <p key={i} className={ item[0] < 0.5 ? 'low-value' : 'high-value' }>{ item[1] }</p>
)
```

Then you can use [deconstructing assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to make this cleaner and give each value a named local variable.

```
data.content.map(([value, text, array], i) =>
  <p key={i} className={ value < 0.5 ? 'low-value' : 'high-value' }>{ text }</p>
)
```

Comment: Hmm, this only outputs the first paragraph of the text. And if I change it to item[2] I get the second paragraph etc.

Comment: It works with the data fragment you've posted: https://codepen.io/Squeegy/pen/WNQdPeM?editors=0110

Comment: Correct. Is it maybe because my data are fetched with JSON stringify? I map all my data correctly, everything is displayed correctly but not able to do this one thing with the classes